# Bitmap indexes: are they not good for DML operations?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two partitoned tables on weekly interval called table1 and table2 and each table has columns like

- SR_NO,
- CARD_NUMBER,
- TRANSACTION_DATE and
- STATUS which contains only values like 'N' or 'P' or 'Y'.

I have created two indexes on both tables.

First one is normal local index on TRANSACTION_DATE and STATUS.

Second index is bitmap index on STATS.

I am comparing two tables like as shown in below select statement.

```
select a.sr_no, a.transacton_date, a.record_status 
from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.card_number = b.card_number 
              and a.transaction_date = b.transaction_date 
              and a.Status = 'P' 
              and b.staus = 'P';
```

I am looping through above select satement data and updating STATUS column to 'Y' for matched data in table1 and updating 5000 records at a time using bulk insert concept and update statement is as follows i have used bind variables also in update statement.

```
update table1 set 
  status = 'Y' 
  where transaction_date = :date 
    and SR_NO = :SRNO 
    and STATUS = :status;
```

Bind varable assigned with select statement returned data.

Now my problem is above update statement is taking time then up on co ordination with our internal DBA team they suggested to drop bitmap indexes which slows down perfomance of DML statements.

I want to know is it true that bitmap indexes slows down performance of DML statements.

Comment: Yes it is true, bitmap indexes should not be used in OTLP systems.

Comment: @user1463065:  There is no usage of bitmap index ,if we compare both the predicates of `SELECT` as well as the `UPDATE` statement , infact both should use index created on the `transaction_date and status` ,there is always a cost in maintaining indexes ,still can you please share the `explain plan`